# Flies in apartment bathroom

Tags: bathroom, pest-control, insect

As of about 1-2 months ago, I've had these small, black flies constantly show up in my apartment bathroom. They show up in the bathtub more than anything else, sometimes on the shower curtain, sometimes on the walls. Even inside of my toilet bowl somehow (I never leave that open). My bathtub's faucet has been constantly leaking, so I assume this is part of the problem. Looked around online, and these are likely drain flies going from the description.

Used some methods I had read about like pouring water I boiled in a kettle down the sink and bathtub drains, to very little effect. So I ordered some [Green Gobbler Fruit Fly Killer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CVM269Q) (Drain Flies also listed). Poured some of this down my bathtub's drain on early Sunday morning, but this also didn't seem to have any effect. These flies are still showing up in the same locations around my bathroom.

To add some detail, there are two houseplants in my apartment's living room. Due to appearances from other bugs, I've limited watering to once per week, and have used a mix of Water + low amount of Hydrogen Peroxide to water them instead, as well as coating the top of the plants with some [Diatomaceous Earth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01D60GAW2) after watering. I realize that I made a mistake in not getting the food grade version of this.

What I've found is that after getting into the habit of keeping my bathroom door closed when these flies were showing up, these flies very rarely ever appear outside of that room. This is where I assume they're spawning from.

Any help would be appreciated, since I've lost what little patience I've got after killing 3-4 of these things almost every time I enter my bathroom now.

Comment: Moisture draws insects that rely on water to survive, also the house plant. If the exhaust fan does not reduce the humidity, buy a dehumidifier and set it to auto control.

Comment: I have no exhaust fan in my bathroom. There is a window that I can open, would that work in place? I would like to mention that it is below freezing outside, so I don't know how much it could help matters.

Comment: Get a dehumidifier that operates regardless of the weather. Select one that has humidity reading and setting capability. It is good for the health of the bathroom too.

Comment: Wanted to provide an update. So I was able to get some of the maintenance crew into my apartment to fix the leaky faucet, and this was only because the power in my apartment went out the night before. That's another story for another time, though.

Afterwards, the appearance of the drain flies dropped significantly after leaving the drains closed on both my sink and bathtub for a few months. No more drain flies have appeared, but I'm staying vigilant and keeping them closed until I'm sure they're completely gone. Might get some more of that Green Gobbler stuff again.